# Stored procedure to retrieve all foreign key columns with values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which would return a list of foreign key columns + their values (a table with two columns in it), when provided a table name and an ID in that table. It is guaranteed that an ID is unique. The result should contain a number of lines equal to the number of foreign key columns. If no foreign keys were found, a *NULL* row should be generated, e.g. `Key = NULL, Value = NULL`.

Consider the following sample tables and data:

*Employee* table:

```
 Id | Name       | AddressId | JobId 
----|------------|-----------|-------
 1  | John Smith | 2         | 3

Foreign keys:
- FK_Employee_Address
- FK_Employee_Job
```

*Address* table:

```
 Id | Street    | Suite  | City     | Postal Code | CountryId 
----|-----------|--------|----------|-------------|-----------
 2  | 1 Main St | 101    | New York | 10001       | 4

Foreign keys:
- FK_Address_Country
```

*Country* table:

```
 Id | Name
----|------
 4  | USA
```

*Job* table:

```
 Id  | Title
-----|-----------
 3   | Developer
```

**Question:** How do I get all foreign key columns + their values, one per line in the resulting SQL query?

*Test case 1:*

```
spGetForeignKeyColumns 'Employee', 1

Key       | Value
----------|------
AddressId | 2
JobId     | 3
```

*Test case 2:*

```
spGetForeignKeyColumns 'Address', 2

Key       | Value
----------|------
CountryId | 4
```

*Test case 3:*

```
spGetForeignKeyColumns 'Country', 4

Key       | Value
----------|------
NULL      | NULL
```

It's safe to assume that *Id* is always int, so there won't be any type collisions.

**Attempted solution.** I know how to retrieve all foreign key columns for a given table *without a value* using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
    OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id) fk
WHERE TableName = @TableName
```

Which for the above *Employee* table would produce the following result:

```
 ForeignKey          | TableName       | ColumnName | ReferenceTableName | ReferenceColumnName
---------------------|-----------------|------------|--------------------|---------------------
 FK_Employee_Address | Employee        | AddressId  | Address            | Id
 FK_Employee_Job     | Employee        | JobId      | Job                | Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where very close. I used the query you supplied in the question, and added code to retrieve the primary key of the table in question too. All that was left is to build up the SQL to extract the values and execute it dynamically. Try this

```
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(64) = 'Employee',
        @Id     INT = 1,
        @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

--Comment this out to debug
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
SELECT ''' + ColumnName + ''' as [Key], CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), ' + quotename(ColumnName) + ') as Value
FROM ' + quotename(TableName) + ' data
WHERE ' + quotename(primarykey) + ' = @Id
UNION
'
-- Uncomment this to debug...
--SELECT ColumnName, quotename(TableName), quotename(primarykey) 
--The column that returns null is the one with the problem
FROM (    
    SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
        OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
        COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
        OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
        COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName,
        COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) as primarykey
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = f.parent_object_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.is_primary_key = 1 and i.index_id = ic.index_id) fk
WHERE TableName = @TableName

IF NULLIF(@SQL, '') IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL AS [Key], NULL as Value
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 7)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Id INT', @Id
END
```

I didn't run through all your test cases, but this should get you pretty close. Also, I converted the value to VARCHAR because it will throw an error if not all the keys are integers.

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Right now it says `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`, and the generated @SQL is empty (when debugging), but I'm having a hard time understanding the general approach. For example, I see a UNION there, which later gets truncated, so what's the point to add it in the first place? Did you try to run your query against any data? The only thing that's clear to me is that I have to use a dynamic SQL query. Is there any other way? I'd imagine this would be hard to debug, even if it worked.

Comment: I ran it against a table on one of my local dbs. It works fine. If @SQL is blank, it means your relationships are not setup the same as mine, and you probably need to tweak the primary key retrieval. The select statement will be repeated for every foreign key, and there will be a UNION at the end of the Query which needs to be truncated... If the main query doesn't return any records, then the LEFT will fail. Remove the \@SQL = \@SQL + ' portion to see what the main query returns. I'll update the answer to cater for tables with no foreign keys